Conjecture closed form of summation over an integer lattice

Conjecture:
$$\forall \Lambda,\ \exists P(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x],\ S(\Lambda):=\sum_{k\in\Lambda}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+k_{j}^2}=\frac{\pi^{n}}{\sinh^{n}(\pi)\operatorname{d}(\Lambda)}P\left(\cosh\left(\frac{\pi}{\operatorname{d}(\Lambda)}\right)\right)$$
where $\Lambda=\bigl\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j v_j|\ a_j \in \mathbb{Z}\bigl\}$, $V=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, $\operatorname{d(\Lambda)}=|\det(V)|\ $, $V$ is an integer matrix.

The conjecture is known to be true for $n=1$ or $\operatorname{d}(\Lambda)=1$, I also checked some few cases when $n=2$:
$$\operatorname{d(\Lambda)}=2\implies P(x)\in \{4x^4-4x^2+2,\ 4x^4-2x^2\} \tag{1}$$
This corresponds to 2 lattice structures with $\operatorname{d(\Lambda)}=2$ in dimension $2$.
 
And for
$V=\{(4,1)^T,(1,1)^T\}\implies P(x)=16x^6-24x^4+11x^2$;
$V=\{(3,1)^T,(2,2)^T\}\implies P(x)=64x^8-128x^6+88x^4-24x^2+4$
As I mentioned in this previous question, I don't have a good way to compute this sum, all calculations and simplifications was done by calculator and each result took me quite a lot of time.
Unfortunately, I cannot compute the sum when $n\geq 3$ because it is too much for my calculator to handle. However, partial calculation ($n=3$) suggested that closed form is achievable.

Update
Slightly deviated from the main goal, I found out that $S(\Lambda)$ has a nice integral representation:
$$\sum_{k\in \Lambda}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}d^{n}x\exp{(-\|x\|_{1}+i\langle 
k,x \rangle)}=2^{n}S(\Lambda)$$
After some investigation, I think that $\sum_{k\in \Lambda} e^{i\langle k,x \rangle}$ is a distribution similar to Dirac comb, I couldn't find its formula though. If the formula of distribution is known, the integral can be turned into something like a geometric sum. I also noticed if that is the case, $\operatorname{d}(\Lambda)$ should be the "angular frequency". ()

(Edited)
My question is:
How do we find
$$\sum_{k\in \Lambda} e^{i\langle 
k,x \rangle}$$
Does this give an answer to the conjecture?

Here is my attempt to solve it
First, we transform the sum (using Laplace transform):
$$S(\Lambda)=\sum_{k\in\Lambda}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+k_{j}^2}=\sum_{k\in\Lambda}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}dx_{j}e^{-x_{j}}\cos(k_{j}x_{j})=\sum_{k\in\Lambda}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}dx_{j}e^{-|x_{j}|+ik_{j}x_{j}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{k\in\Lambda}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}d^{n}x\ e^{-\|x\|_{1}+ik^{T}x}=\frac{1}{2^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}d^{n}x\ e^{-\|x\|_{1}}\sum_{k\in\Lambda}e^{ik^{T}x} \tag{1}$$
Now, we manipulate the differential form $d^{n}x\sum_{k\in\Lambda}e^{ik^{T}x}$. Given that $k=Va\ (a\in\mathbb{Z}^n)$ :
$$d^{n}x\sum_{k\in\Lambda}e^{ik^{T}x}=d^{n}x\sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}^n}e^{ia^{T}V^{T}x}=d^{n}x\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{a_{j}\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{ia_{j}(V^{T}x)_{j}}$$
$$=d^{n}x\prod_{j=1}^{n}2\pi\sum_{a_{j}\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta((V^{T}x)_{j}-2\pi a_{j})=d^{n}t\frac{(2\pi)^{n}}{|\det(V)|}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{a_{j}\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(t_{j}-2\pi ((V^{T})^{-1}a)_{j})$$
$$=d^{n}t\frac{(2\pi)^{n}}{|\det(V)|}\sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}}\delta(t-2\pi(V^{T})^{-1}a) \tag{2}$$
I just used substitution (with the integral bound staying the same) and Dirac comb to achieve expression at $(2)$. Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get:
$$S(\Lambda)=\frac{\pi^{n}}{|\det(V)|}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}d^{n}t\ e^{-\|x\|_{1}}\sum_{a\in \mathbb{Z}^n}\delta(t-2\pi(V^{T})^{-1}a)$$
$$=\frac{\pi^{n}}{|\det(V)|}\sum_{a\in \mathbb{Z}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} d^{n}t\ e^{-\|x\|_{1}}\delta(t-2\pi(V^{T})^{-1}a)$$
$$=\frac{\pi^{n}}{|\det(V)|}\sum_{a\in \mathbb{Z}^n}\exp{(-2\pi\|(V^{T})^{-1}a\|_{1})} \tag{3}$$
With different appropriate constraints on $a$, we can remove the absolute symbol, leaving us with geometric sums with common base $e^{-2\pi/|\det(V)|}$. From here, after some algebra, we see that the statement of conjecture is true (the algebra I'm talking about here is not obvious though, so the proof of this conjecture is not completed literally). But the good thing is that we know the closed form of $S(\Lambda)$ always exists and we should be able to find it.
If there is any gap in my answer, please tell me.
